# iPhone -- Why doesn't touchesBegan fire on UIViews when alpha is set to zero?

Tags: iphone

Is there some optimization going on that removes the view or something? I still want it to recieve touch events even though I've made it transparent. Seems these events don't fire if alpha == 0 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, [touches don't get detected on transparent views](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html):

"By default, a view receives touch events, but you can set its userInteractionEnabled property to NO to turn off delivery of events. A view also does not receive events if it’s hidden or if it’s transparent."

How about setting the view to 1% alpha, or even a few points? Maybe your UI should show a ghost overlay anyways.

The other thing you could do is make a UIView subclass, frame it to the same size, and overlay it. A UIView has a background color of [UIColor clearColor] by default, but you can still detect touches on it.

Comment: Setting the alpha to 0.001 has the same effect as setting it to zero. Seems to me your clearcolor view is a safer/better approach.

Comment: Touches are ignored when the alpha of a view is less than 0.1.

Comment: With clearColor even on a UIView, you cannot detect touches. Although at least with iOS 8 it seems it will detect touches with alpha 0.01 instead of 0.1 which is nice!

Comment: Yup, just tested 0.01 alpha and it works. I find it annoying that a clearColor view cannot receive touches. They definitely should be getting touches, at least a property to enable this would be better.